# Would you expect MySql to drop records if bombed by inserts on the same table?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I don't have a testing environment for this yet. But before I think too much about solutions I'd like to know if people think this would be a problem.

I will have 10-20 java processes connected to a MySql db via JDBC. Each will be inserting unique records, all going to the same table. The rate of inserts will be on the order of 1000's per second.

My expectation is that some process will attempt to insert and encounter a table lock while another process is inserting, and this will result in a JDBC exception and that insert to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use InnoDB as it supports reads and writes at the same time.  MyISAM will usually lock the table during the insert, but give preference to SELECT statements.  This can cause issues if you're doing reporting or visualization of the data while trying to do inserts.

If you have a natural primary key (no auto_increment), using it will help avoid some deadlock issues.  (Newer versions have fixed this.)

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/09/26/innodb-auto-inc-scalability-fixed/

You might also want to see if you can queue your writes in memory and send them to the database in batches.  Lots of little inserts will be much slower than doing batches in transactions.

Good presentation on getting the most out of the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver:
http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/21/Connector_J%20Performance%20Gems%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: Do you just mean doing many inserts in fewer transactions vs doing fewer inserts in many transactions?

Comment: Many inserts wrapped in a few transactions will be faster.  The database doesn't actually have to write it to disk until the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly if you increase the insert rate sufficiently there eventually will be a point where some buffer somewhere fills up faster than it can be emptied. When such a buffer hits its maximum capacity and can't contain any more data some of your insert statements will have to fail. This will result in an exception being thrown at the client.

However, assuming you have high-end hardware I don't imagine this should happen with 1000 inserts per second, but it does depend on the specific hardware, how much data there is per insert, how many indexes you have, what other queries are running on the system simultaneously, etc.

Regardless of whether you are doing 10 inserts per second or 1000 you still shouldn't blindly assume that every insert will succeed - there's always a chance that an insert will fail because of some network communication error or some other problem. Your application should be able to correctly handle the situation where an insert fails.

Comment: That makes sense. We'll need a retry mechanism for failed inserts as well as a large queue. There will be 10-20 processes each inserting thousands of rows per second. The h/w will be high-end.

Answer (score 1):

What engine do you use? That can make a difference.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/concurrent-inserts.html